# What are the advantages and disadvantages of being in human form?

Tags: dark-souls

In Dark Souls, what are the advantages and disadvantages of being in human form?

In Demon's Souls, being in human form gives you a clear HP advantage, but attacks have lower power and you can be invaded (if playing online).

In Dark Souls, however, the advantages and disadvantages are less clear. What are they?

Comment: Why waste drop chances? You get to be invaded, which sucks, plus you're gonna die sometime and lose human form anyway. Waste of time I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Advantages of human form are that you can kindle camp fires and summon phantoms to aid you.  These abilities are not available in Hollow form.

The only disadvantage is you're risking black phantom invasions.

Comment: In addition to the above, being in human form also increases drop rates for items.

Comment: @asmodai No it does not. **Humanity** increases drop rate. Whether your human or not has no effect.

Comment: So assuming I'm not having Estus problems and want to play alone, there's _no downside_ to playing Hollowed?

Comment: No. But I rather like the excitement that comes with being at risk of being invaded so I try to play as human whenever I can.

Comment: @Wipqozn Mmm, I must have misread humanity as being human somewhere then. Mea culpa.

Comment: "Summon phantoms to aid you" includes the NPC, Solaire of Astoria. He can only aid you in human form.

Comment: There are story-related reasons for being human, as well as additional encounters you may have if you are in human form before defeating an area's boss. Also you have additional resistances while human. http://darksouls.wikidot.com/human

Answer (score 0):

True you will get tips and different encounters when in human form, also stacking humanity in human form increases your stats.